# How to paint a particular area eg. t-shirt in a image without selecting it using android?

Tags: android

Im trying to change the color of a t-shirt in android. The image contains a t-shirt with a background. I don't like to go for a png file.

I want to know how to find the edges of the t-shirt so that we can paint the particular area.

Is there any way to do it??

Thanks and Regards,
Srinivasan

Comment: did you succeed in doing that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try some algorithm of Edge detection. Look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_recognition) wiki.